# Cannot Delete List Columns

Tags: sharepoint, moss

I am having problems deleting columns from a form library in MOSS 2007.  When I go to the form library settings, the columns are listed and the note in the column header says "click to edit" (and delete).  However, only certain columns are even clickable.  Why is that and how can I delete the ones that are not clickable?

Answer (score 3):

It isn't `ReadOnly`, it is `FromBaseType`.

Set `FromBaseType="FALSE"` and you'll see the "Delete" button showing up on your library/list settings form.

Good luck,

vinz

Answer (score 2):

Before you can delete a field, you need to set its `ReadOnlyField` property to `false`.

```
f.ReadOnlyField = false;
f.Update(true);
s.Lists[ListName].Update();
f.Delete();
```

Answer (score 1):

The rules in listedit.aspx for a field to show up as a non-link is that the field should be marked as ReadOnly, not be hidden and have XPath set.

So these fields probably contain promoted properties.

You may be able to delete them by using [SharePoint Manager](http://spm.codeplex.com), but be sure to test it on a backup in a test environment as you might break things

Comment: Thanks for listing the rules, I was not aware of that.  Unfortunately, SharePoint Manager did not allow me to delete the columns.  Maybe some code will do it.

Comment: If SharePoint Manager can't then code can't either, but it may be a multistep process. Set Column not ReadOnly, Save, Set column not Sealed, Save, Delete

Answer (score 0):

Do they belong to a specific Content Type?

Comment: Some do, others don't.  There seems to be no relation between a column's being clickable and whether it is attached to a content type.